# Will I be able to spread out my soul level or do I have to focus on a single teammate?

Tags: soul-hackers-2

When I am choosing what teammate to side with in certain conversations, I am currently choosing whatever teammate has the lowest soul level because I'm just assuming you'll be able to reach the latest soul level with each teammate.

Is this assumption true? Are you able to spread out your soul level points or do you have to focus on leveling up a single teammate in order to reach their max soul level?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reach the final level of all of the teammates, you'll have to eventually play in NG+ with the addition of added soul gain granted to you by a NG+ option.

The amounts needed for first playthrough and NG+ are highlighted below in spoilers in case you don't want to know what the actual numbers are.

First:

> 100

NG+:

> 200

on your last